# Writing compose from scratch, how do parameters get passed down?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, scope, closures

I was tasked with having to write compose from scratch, here are the requirements:

Write Compose and Pipe functions.

Step 1: Implement the function Compose:

Compose should return a function that is the composition of a list of
functions of arbitrary length.

Each function is called on the return value of the function that follows.

You can view compose as moving right to left through its arguments.

Compose Example:

```
var greet = function(name){ return 'hi: ' + name;}
var exclaim = function(statement) { return statement.toUpperCase() + '!';}
var welcome = compose(greet, exclaim);
welcome('phillip'); // 'hi: PHILLIP!'
```

I was able to get things working using mainly intuition, here is my solution:

```
var compose = function() {
  var args = arguments
  return function(param) {
    var result = param
    for (let i = args.length -1; i >=0; i --) {
      result = args[i](result)
    }
    return result
  }

};
```

What I don't understand is: How does 'phillip' get passed down to params? Compose doesn't have any way to access it

Comment: I don’t understand  the problem. The string is passed **directly** to the `param` argument.

Comment: @Quentin How though, compose doesn't take in any parameters so how is `param` accessed from within compose?

Comment: It isn’t. It’s accessed from `welcome`!

Answer (score 0):

```
const compose = (...funcs) => params =>
  funcs.reduceRight((value, func) => func(value), params)
```

First of all, I have diverged from your implementation of function compose.

Parameters, `params`, passed as the second parameter, `initValue`, of the `reduceRight` function so the first function call is made with it. Note first function call is to the last function in the `funcs` array.

Usage:

```
compose(x => x**2, x => x/2)(2); // returns 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass result from **exclaim** func into **greet** func as argument

```
const greet = (name) => 'hi: ' + name;
const exclaim = (statement) => statement.toUpperCase() + '!';
const compose = (f1,f2) => (name) => f1(f2(name))
const welcome = compose(greet, exclaim);
welcome('phillip');
// 'hi: PHILLIP!'
```

Comment: No. The code uses `arguments` so it can handle a variable number of arguments.